# SQL all records from table1 and the records from table2, but more

Tags: sql, join

I have a customer table and a ship to table. There is a one-to-many relationship, but there doesn't have to be a ship to for the customer.

I know:

```
select c.customer,s.shipto
from custtable AS c
left join shiptotable AS s on c.customer=s.customer
```

Will pull all records from the customer, and show the ship to for the customer (or NULL if the customer doesn't have a ship to).

But, what i want is all the customers, and ALWAYS show NULL for the first ship to, and then show any others.

Something like

```
CustA       NULL
CustA       SHIP1
CustA       SHIP2
CustB       NULL
CustC       NULL
CustC       SHIP5
etc
```

is there a way to do that with inner/left/right/outer joins? i know i can do it with a union, i would just prefer not to use a union.

thanks.

Comment: It's extremely obvious to do this with a union and I can't think of any reason why you would want to avoid unions.

Comment: Just a thought, but naming your tables `custtable` and `shiptotable` seems overly redundant.

Comment: **Why** do you want a `null` ship-to entry?  If this is for reporting reasons (you want a header), handle that in your application layer.  Otherwise, what are you doing with this information?

Comment: it is for a report, so we need the sales for the customers that weren't tied to a ship to and also sales where they were tied to a ship to. the view has functions reading the history based off the incoming customer and shipto, so that is why i need customer NULL shipto, and customer NOTNULL shipto.   I guess i will just use a union.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by breaking some rules. You could include a **(null,null)** pair in the shipto table and adjust your WHERE clause to make sure it always gets picked.

```
INSERT INTO shipto VALUES ('Harry','Privet Drive')
INSERT INTO shipto VALUES ('Harry','Hogwarts')
INSERT INTO shipto VALUES (null,null)
```

You can use coalesce to make sure that the null gets listed first

```
select c.customer,s.shipto
from custtable AS c
left join shipto AS s on c.customer=s.customer OR s.customer IS NULL
order by c.customer,coalesce(s.shipto,'')
```

That gives

```
Harry  NULL
Harry  Hogwarts
Harry  Privet Drive
Ron    NULL
```

Of course you *should* have a primary key on every table and if you do that the shipto table cannot have a (null,null) row.

Comment: I don't think that will work I believe you need to add it to a GROUP BY since s.shipto is aggregate

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all record but null first then use flowing script

```
select c.customer,s.shipto from custtable AS c
left join shiptotable AS s on c.customer=s.customer
order by shiptotable.shipto
```

if you want to according to customer and null of that customer first like below

CustA       NULL
 CustA       SHIP1
 CustA       SHIP2
 CustB       NULL
 CustC       NULL
 CustC       SHIP5
etc

then you use the flowing script

```
select c.customer,s.shipto from custtable AS c
left join shiptotable AS s on c.customer=s.customer
order by custtable.customer, shiptotable.shipto
```